# What values can you put inside nginx.conf when using it as a reverse proxy in a dockerized app, and does it have to change for production deployment?

Tags: docker, nginx

```
upstream loadbalancer {
server 172.17.0.1:5001 weight=6;
server 172.17.0.1:5002 weight=4;
}
server {
location / {
proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
}}
```

Can we use 172.17.0.1 as IP in a dockerized application, what does this ip point to?

Also, can we put anything we want as proxy_pass? I looked at several configs and it seems to be the case.

https://towardsdatascience.com/sample-load-balancing-solution-with-docker-and-nginx-cf1ffc60e644?gi=924cd636af26

I got the configs from there.

```
version: '3'
services:
app1:
build: ./app1
ports:
- "5001:5000"
app2:
build: ./app2
ports:
- "5002:5000"
nginx:
build: ./nginx
ports:
- "8080:80"
depends_on:
- app1
- app2
```

It seems that the only thing you need to enter correctly is the port number, although in the app above we seem to port both request to the same application that serving port 5000. Since both 5001 and 5002 redirects to 5000.

Answer (score 0):

When you bring up a compose stack, docker creates a custom bridge network and those IPs refer to the endpoints/applications in the network.

That said, you shouldn't be relying on IP addresses. Since you're using compose, attach them to the same network and refer to service by the service name instead of IPs. Your compose also has incorrect indentation so the entire config is incorrect.

The compose should look like so:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: ./app1
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - app
  app2:
    build: ./app2
    ports:
      - "5002:5000"
    networks:
      - app:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2
    networks: 
      - app:

networks:
  app:
```

Note the `networks` key which puts the apps and nginx on the same network. Now you can refer to services by their service name, and in nginx config it should look like:

```
upstream loadbalancer {
  server app1:5001 weight=6;
  server app2:5002 weight=4;
}
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
  }
}
```